# Can we have RBAC assignment for every folders inside a blob container of Azure storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I have checked the storage account and don't see any possibility to have nested containers with RBAC policies through portal.

Can some one please take a look and share their thoughts if this is possible or achievable.

Comment: What kind of storage account is it - regular blob storage or ADLS Gen2?

Comment: @Kartik Thanks for your help. Yes, based on documentation its not possible with native RBAC. Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

•   As per the official Microsoft documentation, **it is not possible to create nested containers in a storage account, i.e., create containers beneath one another**. Thus, `in a container, you can only upload blobs or files as per your requirement but cannot create storage entities in it other than the original container created in the root of the storage account`. You can refer to the below documentation link for reference: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-container-create#create-a-container***

Thus, **`you can have RBAC assignments on the root container entity and further on the blob level, you can assign the permissions through access policy by defining permissions on it accordingly`**.

•   Also, **the same for a file share, but in it, we can create multiple nested directories within one another, but we can apply RBAC assignments and the inherent permissions on the root file share created only**. *`Further, for every share created within it, if you map the directory on a Windows system or Linux system, then you can configure the ACLs for it accordingly like which user in on-premises or Azure AD who has logged in has the permissions to read, write, execute, modify, and delete on that directory.`*

Kindly refer to the below documentation link for more details on the above topics: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-ad-ds-configure-permissions#azure-rbac-permissions***